# Campos en Blanco en un DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, datetime, datetimepicker

Tengo algunos datos de fecha nulos en mi base de datos, sin embargo cuando quiero editar al momento de copiar los datos, los DateTimePicker donde se supone deben ser nulos, se inician con la fecha del día. ¿Qué condicionales puedo usar para que aparezca en blanco cuando son nulos?.

Éste es mi código:

```
private void dgvDaily_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //Formulario donde se abren
        frmEditar Editar = new frmEditar();



        Editar.lblId.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtSalesOrderE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtCustomer.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtTotalE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtTotalTicketE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtModel.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmpDateReceived.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmpDueDate.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        Editar.cmbPriorityEstatus.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        Editar.cmbCategoria.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        Editar.cmbPz_Por_Hora.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmpCut.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmp630a830.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[13].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmp830a1030.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmp1030a1230.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[15].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmp1230a230.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[16].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmp230a430.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[17].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmp430a630.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[18].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmpSewingGroupB.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[19].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmpInspection.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[20].Value.ToString();
        Editar.dtmpReadyToShip.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[21].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtShippedDate.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[22].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtShippingContainersE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[23].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtCommentsE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[24].Value.ToString();
        Editar.cmbPoints_Unitarians.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[25].Value.ToString();
        Editar.txtTotalPointsE.Text = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[26].Value.ToString(); 
        Editar.cmbPriorityE.Text= dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[27].Value.ToString();




        Editar.Show();

    }
```

Comment: Tienes todos los campos como texto, no será que recibes un DateTime?

Comment: que me recomendarias hacer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que puedes intentar es lo siguiente. Si la fecha tiene un valor nulo le asignas un formato personalizado con un espacio.

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
```

Pero deberás cambiar el formato en cuanto el usuario cambie manualmente el valor, lo puedes hacer con el evento `ValueChanged`:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
  dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}
```

**EDITO**
Si el valor de entrada por ejemplo es `dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value` para el DateTimePicker denominado `dtmpDateReceived` deberás poner un condicional:

```
if (IsNullOrEmpty(dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value)) {
   dtmpDateReceived.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   dtmpDateReceived.CustomFormat = " ";
} else {
   dtmpDateReceived.Value = dgvDaily.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value;
}
```

Al margen de tener siempre

```
private void dtmpDateReceived_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dtmpDateReceived.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
  dtmpDateReceived.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}
```

Comment: y como puedo realizar la condicionar para saber si es null o no el campo en la base de datos? llegue utilizar if (dtmpicker.value = null) y no me funciono

Comment: He editado la respuesta con el condicional

Comment: Excelente tu aportacion, me servira de mucho, muchas gracias!